# Excel VBA Issues - SUM, Ranges, Values, etc

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using VBA within MS Access for years  and have some general VBA competence.  I now need to start using VBA within Excel and I am running into all sorts of problems.  I am sorry to bug you all, but I just cannot get this to work and I have spent over a day researching the web and carefully testing each option.

Ultimately, I am trying to automate an Access import from Excel spreadsheets.  I think this is a fairly common objective and I think my plans for Excel VBA are pretty straightforward:

1)  Get a record Count from the Spreadsheet (used to verify successful import)
2)  Get a SUM of all Values in a specific column (also used to verify successful import)
3)  Add a new Column to contain File Name s (Add Header and then Add a fixed value – file name – to each row with data)

I don’t know whether my problems are how I refer to Workbook/Worksheet/Cell/Range etc., or some other fundamental misunderstanding of VBA.

What is also frustrating is the fact that the first time I run this, some parts DO work, but then they start failing with each subsequent run.
I am using Access & Excel 2010.

I have lumped all of these processes into a single function for two reasons.  First, it makes testing easier.  Second, I cannot figure out how to create separate functions which would work on an open/active Spreadsheet. (So if you have insight on that I welcome that as well).

The Code is pasted below and the comments include info re what works/doesn’t work.

Thank you very much for any insights into the problems with my code.

DGP

---

```
Public Function fnProcessExcelDataImportFiles(strFileNameAndPath As String, strUseWorksheet As String, strSUMColumn As String,  strAddColumnLabel As String, varAddColumnFixedValue As Variant)
On Error GoTo HandleError

'Variables

Dim strColumnCLabel As String
Dim varColumnCLabel As Variant
Dim intLastCol As Long
Dim intLastRow As Long
Dim intNextCol As Long

Dim intRecordCount As Long
Dim varSumExcelColumns As Variant
Dim strSUMRange As String
Dim strNewFixedValueInsteadofVARIANT As String


Dim oXLApp As Excel.Application       'Declare the object variables
Dim oXLBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set oXLApp = New Excel.Application      'Create a new instance of Excel
Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileNameAndPath) 'Open the existing workbook
Set oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(1)  'Work with the first worksheet


  oXLSheet.Activate                   'Activate the Worksheet
  oXLApp.Visible = True               'Show it to the user
  oXLApp.UserControl = True


'For Testing:  Verify that function can read from Worksheet
            ‘THESE WORKED!!
            varColumnCLabel = oXLSheet.Cells(1, 13).Value
            strColumnCLabel = oXLSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value


'Get Last Row & Record Count – THIS WORKED

intLastRow = oXLSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
intRecordCount = intLastRow - 1



'Get SUM for Parameter Column

strSUMRange = strSUMColumn & "2:" & strSUMColumn & intLastRow

'This works once and then returns ZERO each time I run the SUB again?????
varSumExcelColumns = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(oXLSheet.Range(strSUMRange))

                msgbox "SUM From Excel Worksheet: " & varSumExcelColumns

'This works Once and then causes ERROR each time the SUB is subsequently run
'varSumExcelColumns = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("M:M")) 'This throws ERRORS when used more than once???

                'msgbox "SUM From Excel Worksheet: " & varSumExcelColumns

' This also works only Once and then throws ERRORS??????
'varSumExcelColumns = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns(13))
                'msgbox "SUM From Excel Worksheet: " & varSumExcelColumns

'Get Last Column – THIS WORKS
intLastCol = oXLSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
intNextCol = intLastCol + 1

'Add Label and Fixed Value Data to New Column




 oXLSheet.Cells(1, 13).Value = strAddColumnLabel  'This WORKS

oXLSheet.Cells(1, intNextCol).Value = strAddColumnLabel  ‘THIS DOES NOT WORK

 ' This throws an ERROR
 'oXLSheet.Range(Cells(2, intLastCol), Cells(intLastRow, intLastCol)).Value = varAddColumnFixedValue

  ' This throws an ERROR also
  'oXLSheet.Range(Cells(2, 23), Cells(17, 23)).Value = varAddColumnFixedValue

    'This did NOT work
    oXLSheet.Range("X3:X7").Value = varAddColumnFixedValue

    'Check to see if the Range did get updated  
    strNewValue = oXLSheet.Range("x5").Value
    msgbox "New Value = " & strNewValue             'strNewValue is EMPTY

  strNewFixedValueInsteadofVARIANT = CStr(varAddColumnFixedValue)

  'Does it work if I set the new value to a String instead of variant??
  'NO - this does NOT work either
  oXLSheet.Range("X3:X7").Value = strNewFixedValueInsteadofVARIANT

 'Check to see if the Range did get updated - It did NOT
    strNewValue = oXLSheet.Range("x5").Value
    msgbox "New Value = " & strNewValue  'strNewValue is EMPTY

Exit_label:

    oXLBook.Close SaveChanges:=True    'Save (and disconnect from) the Workbook


    oXLApp.Quit                         'Close (and disconnect from) Excel
    Set oXLSheet = Nothing               'Disconnect from all Excel objects (let the user take over)
    Set oXLBook = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    fnProcessExcelDataImportFiles = -777

Exit Function

HandleError:
    msgbox "Error during fnProcessExcelDataImportFiles - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_label
End Function



Public Sub TestfnProcessExcelDataImportFiles()

Dim strFileNameAndPath As String
Dim strUseWorksheet As String
Dim intSUMColumn As Integer
Dim strSUMColumn As String
Dim strAddColumnLabel As String
Dim varAddColumnFixedValue As Variant

Dim dblSUMFromFunction As Double

strFileNameAndPath = "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxx\FileNamexxx_2Mar17.xlsx"
strUseWorksheet = "Sheet1"
intSUMColumn = 13
strSUMColumn = "M"
strAddColumnLabel = "PleaseWork"
varAddColumnFixedValiue = 333.33


dblSUMFromFunction = fnProcessExcelDataImportFiles(strFileNameAndPath, strUseWorksheet, strSUMColumn, strAddColumnLabel, varAddColumnFixedValue)

End Sub
```

Comment: First steps toward fixing this: 1) `Option Explicit` (you have typos in some variable names, i.e. `varAddColumnFixedValiue`) 2) qualify all your ranges.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Sorry, but could you please be a bit more specific when you say "qualify all of your ranges".

Comment: I saw some places where you use `Cells` without a `dot` before, specifically in those commented lines that throw errors.

Comment: This is where my ignorance gets me.  I had seen some posts online with .Cells and I did try that, but it would not run and gave me an error:  
Invalid or unqualified reference

I just tried again to change the code to: oXLSheet.Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(17, 23)).Value = strNewFixedValueInsteadofVARIANT    Error Again.  So, I think you have hit on one of my key problems, but I don't know the proper syntax to fix it.

Comment: I did not mean just adding a dot, like `.Cells` but `someSheetObject.Cells`. eventually you can use a `With` bloc, specifying the sheet once, in that case you can use single dot.

Comment: Anyway I think it is more urgent is to set `option explicit` and fix variable name typos.

Comment: UPDATE. The Option Explicit did help, but I am still getting ZERO for the SUM most of the times that it runs.  Still no clue why that is inconsistent (works once, and then fails after).
'Get SUM for Parameter Column
strSUMRange = strSUMColumn & "2:" & strSUMColumn & intLastRow
'This works once and then returns ZERO each time I run the SUB again  
varSumExcelColumns = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(oXLSheet.Range(strSUMRange))

I also don’t understand what is wrong with this code below:
oXLSheet.Range(Cells(2, intLastCol), Cells(intLastRow, intLastCol)).Value = varAddColumnFixedValue

Comment: What is the error message it throws?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a line that works the first time and not the second time, the next step to take could be to add extra feedback within your code to check what the variables are doing that are getting passed to the line.

```
'Get SUM for Parameter Column

strSUMRange = strSUMColumn & "2:" & strSUMColumn & intLastRow
```

Add this row

```
msgbox "Variable Check: oXLsheet> " &  oXLSheet & "strSUMRange> " & strSUMRange
```

to see if the variables are changing unexpectedly between runs.

```
'This works once and then returns ZERO each time I run the SUB again?????
varSumExcelColumns = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(oXLSheet.Range(strSUMRange))

msgbox "SUM From Excel Worksheet: " & varSumExcelColumns
```

Comment: Thanks Kev.  I have literally tested/debugged dozens of times with the Locals Window open.  The variables are not changing.  I am going to Re-Post a more limited Question now related just to the SUM issue.  I do appreciate you answering!